# Is writing a compiler based on C basically just writing a program which reads a file?

Tags: compiler-construction

I've been thinking of making a language for personal use (and learning), and as far as I can tell the easiest way to do that would be to write a 'compiler' in C which is basically just a program which reads a file and then does actions depending on what is in the file.

Is there a better way to make a language?

I've been skimming through these two links:

http://scheme2006.cs.uchicago.edu/11-ghuloum.pdf

http://www.stack.nl/~marcov/compiler.pdf

The first however is telling me how to write a compiler which compiles C, but I don't want that.

The second is telling me how to make a compiler based upon on an outdated language (I think), and I don't want my language to be usable only on old machines or something.

So, basically:  I want to write a compiler for my own language, not for other languages.  How do I do this?  Is making the compiler in C a good idea?

Comment: If it "does actions", then it's not a compiler but an interpreter. A compiler translates from one language (the source language) to another (the target language).

Comment: First you write a compiler that compiles your new lang. Then you write a compiler that compiles your new lang in the new lang. Then you compile that, and throw away your old compiler.

Comment: @bright-star That's one way of getting a self-hosting compiler, but that's not required for making a language.

Comment: The linked papers are fine. Naturally you wouldn't make the *same* compiler as they describe, they're just giving an example.

Comment: Wait, there's something I don't understand...  Can I make an interpreter as its own program, so it just runs on its own entirely? (e.g. I make an interpreter in C for my language, then reduce this interpreter into a .exe or something so I can just delete C and still interpret my language)

I think that is what I want to do, if it's possible.

Comment: Ok, I found this https://www.programiz.com/article/difference-compiler-interpreter and now I want to go back to making a compiler for my language.  I will try the method outlined by @bright-star .

Comment: "Can I make an interpreter as its own program, so it just runs on its own entirely?" Yes, if you write an interpreter (or, for that matter, a compiler), in C and compile it, the resulting executable will be able to run on its own just like any other C program.

Comment: @sepp2k does this mean I can just skip the boostrapping step which bright-star referenced?

Comment: Also, if I use C's built in istream thing, is that even close to being efficient, or is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: @Keagan You don't need to bootstrap your compiler unless you want the compiler to be written in your language (I think bright-star may have misread "I want to write a compiler *for* my own language" as "I want to write a compiler *in* my own language").

Comment: @Keagan C doesn't have an "istream thing", that's C++. In any case, it doesn't really matter whether you use C++'s or C's IO functionality to read characters from the file. What matters is what you do with them. You'll probably want to read up on lexers and parsers before you start worrying about which IO to use.

Comment: I see.  Well thanks for the info!  I think so long as just using C's I/O thing to read the whole file to begin with isn't a bad idea, then I can work from there to make the compiler parse everything correctly.

Comment: @Keagan Regarding your "compilers vs. interpreters" link: that's a bit misleading in my opinion. In particular I wouldn't say that an interpreter is "a program that converts program written in high-level language into machine code understood by the computer". Some might (if they use a JIT compiler), but the most simple type of interpreter doesn't translate anything - that is it never generates machine code - it just executes the commands directly (or if it is a bit more advanced it translates the source into some form of byte code and then executes that).

Comment: @sepp2k So my understanding is this (correct me if I'm wrong):  A compiler takes written code (termed high-level code) and after a lot of work translates that into something the computer can work with (low-level code or machine code or whatever).

Comment: What I would want then is a compiler which takes my language and after working with it a lot translates it into C, which in turn works with the code and translates to machine-code and then the program finally executes.

Is this a waste of time, or should I learn how to make the compiler translate my language directly into machine-code (skip the C intermediate step)?

Comment: @Keagan Yes. Though generally we also call something a compiler if the resulting file isn't actually something that the computer can work with, but some other format. For example the Java compiler produces Java bytecode files, which can be run using the Java virtual machine.

Comment: @Keagan Whether you go through C or directly to machine code (or through LLVM) is really up to you. People have done both successfully.

Comment: Oh cool, LLVM was made at University of Illinois!  I just informed them I won't be going to graduate school there :/  What a coincidence lol.